# Python3:requests module headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am creating a download that can be paused using requests module, and I am using the header `Range`.

If the content length is 1000 bytes and the download was paused at 500 bytes(that is `Range:bytes=0-499`). Now, when it is resuming what should be the `Range`?

This:

```
Range:bytes=499-1000
```

Or This:

```
Range:bytes=500-1000
```

Or This:

```
Range:bytes=500-1001
```

Or anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset of the first byte in a range. The last-byte-pos value gives the byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte positions specified are inclusive. Byte offsets start at zero.
>
> If the last-byte-pos value is present, it MUST be greater than or equal to the first-byte-pos in that byte-range-spec, or the byte- range-spec is syntactically invalid. The recipient of a byte-range- set that includes one or more syntactically invalid byte-range-spec values MUST ignore the header field that includes that byte-range- set.
>
> If the last-byte-pos value is absent, or if the value is greater than or equal to the current length of the entity-body, last-byte-pos is taken to be equal to one less than the current length of the entity- body in bytes.

Your answer is:

```
bytes=500-999 or bytes=500-
```

More info in [HTTP protocol RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.1)